# Recursive algorithm - Using a running sum as an argument?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to understand the recursive solution to the following [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-root-to-leaf-numbers/):

> Given a binary tree containing digits from 0-9 only, each root-to-leaf
>   path could represent a number.
>
> An example is the root-to-leaf path 1->2->3 which represents the
>   number 123.
>
> Find the total sum of all root-to-leaf numbers.

Here is the [top voted solution](https://leetcode.com/discuss/20451/short-java-solution-recursion):

```
public int sumNumbers(TreeNode root) {
    return sum(root, 0);
}

public int sum(TreeNode n, int s){
    if (n == null) return 0;
    if (n.right == null && n.left == null) return s*10 + n.val;
    return sum(n.left, s*10 + n.val) + sum(n.right, s*10 + n.val);
}
```

While I usually find recursive solutions intuitive, here the use of `s` confuses me. In a typical recursive approach, we assume that the problems of size `N-1` have been solved, and we use the solutions to solve the problem of size `N`.

But here, the use of `s` seems to require the additional assumption that the problems of size `N+1` have also been solved. Is this the right way to think about it? Is this some special approach to recursion? What are the other problems that are solved in a similar way?

Comment: Here also we are building the solution for problem with size N, using problems with size N-1. The difference is that N represents the subtree height instead of level.

Comment: The trick is that `s` represents the prefix of the number, i.e. the digits from the root to the current node. When you go down one node, you multiply the prefix by 10 (this is a left shift) and add the new digit. When reaching a leaf, `10.s+d` equals the root-to-leaf number.

Answer (score 1):

> In a typical recursive approach, we assume that the problems of size N-1 have been solved, and we use the solutions to solve the problem of size N.

There is a slight misunderstanding here. By definition, [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) means solving bigger instances of problems using the solution of smaller instances. This smaller instance can be anything and not necessary N-1.

Also, smaller instances are not stored typically and if they are, it is called [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

> But here, the use of s seems to require the additional assumption that the problems of size N+1 have also been solved. Is this the right way to think about it?

No, it is not the right way. In this problem, smaller instance means the tree of smaller height. In your case it is N-1 (not N+1).